# Multiple views on one screen

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a controller on which I would like to have a view where I e.g. draw a circle, and then and a textfield and button which can control the size of the circle.

To start with I have created a controller which contains the button & textfield. I have then created the Drawing view (UIView) and added it as `this.View.AddSubview(drawingView)`, but this doesn't seem to work. If I remove the button and textfield from the controller and add the drawing view by `this.Add(drawingView)` it displays the circle, but then I don't have the button & textfield to control the circle.

How should I create a screen, which both contains the button+textfield and the circle, which I have drawn. I would like to somehow separate the drawing view from the button+textfield, but I don't know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the drawingView.Frame?